# The custom seekbar drawable showing transperent seekbar only on Samsung devices i.e. samsung S3

Tags: android, android-layout, samsung-mobile, android-seekbar

I have used vertical seekbar to show the progress, but on other devices its looks very great but only on samsung devices the seekbar background appears transperant,

[image]

as you can see the progress diffrence between samsung and moto, i want out put like moto.

one sample progress drawable.xml for seekbar background:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
        <size
            android:width="@dimen/_42sdp"
            android:height="@dimen/_42sdp" />
    </shape>
</item>


<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:gravity="bottom"  >
    <clip android:clipOrientation="horizontal" >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#FABD15"/>
            <size
                android:width="@dimen/_42sdp"
                android:height="@dimen/_42sdp" >
                </size>

        </shape>

    </clip>
</item>
```

Comment: can you post the code you are using for the seekbar including the xmls for the drawables?

Comment: i have just edited my que. please check.